# $\phi(m)/m$ is minimal

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working on a number  theory exam and this question seems quite interesting. How do I really approach it?

Determine the element $n_k$ of the set {$m \in N: w(m)=k$}  for which $\phi(m)/m$ is minimum. Here $w(m)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of $m$.

What is lim sup $\phi(m)/m$ for $m \in N$?

Comment: Is equal to $1$.. Just search for totient function on Wikipedia ;-)

Comment: Yeah I know that one thank you! But what about the element for which it reaches minimum? @Ant

Comment: What is $w(m)$? Is it $\omega(m)$?

Answer (score 1):

- For the first problem use the following formula: if $n=\prod_{i=1}^kq_i^{\alpha_i}$ where $q_i$ are primes and $\alpha_i$ are positive integers then :
  $$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}=\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac{1}{q_i}\right)$$
  which is minimal when all $q_i$ are small, so the minimum is reached when $q_1,\cdots,q_k$ are the first prime of $\Bbb Z^+$ hence $n_k=2^{\alpha_1}3^{\alpha_2}5^{\alpha_3}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ where $p_k$ denotes the $k$-th prime. And the element $n_k$ is not unique because if the prime divisors of $n$ and $m$ are the same then clearly $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}=\frac{\varphi(m)}{m}$., in the formula we can take any values of the positive elements $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k$.
- For the second question , think about prime numbers